# Using Adal.js in Angular 7

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am developing a web application using **Angular 7** and this app communicates to a Web API back-end services written in dot.net core.

These two applications have been deployed to Azure and all its configurations has been set up: resource group, enable CORS, Azure AD, etc...

The problem I am facing is at the moment to consume the endpoints, lets say to do a normal get. I am getting a **401 http error** which make sense. So, I starting implementing **Adal.js** in my Angular App to let the user authenticate to the Azure Active Directory, get the token and inject the token on the Request Header (following this post: [Using ADAL.js with Angular4+](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-adal-js-with-angular4/)). However, I am getting this error:

adal.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { adal } from 'adal-angular';
import { Observable, Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AdalConfigService } from './adal-config.service';

declare var AuthenticationContext: adal.AuthenticationContextStatic;
let createAuthContextFn: adal.AuthenticationContextStatic = AuthenticationContext;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AdalService {
  private context: adal.AuthenticationContext;
  constructor(private configService: AdalConfigService) {
    this.context = new createAuthContextFn(configService.adalSettings);
  }
```

Error:
[image]

I already have the following Adal.js packages installed: 
  **npm install adal-angular**
  **npm install @type/adal-angular**

Has anyone face a similar issue? Any help is very welcome

Answer (score 0):

Since `@types/adal` has been replaced  with `@types/adal-angular`, it appears the way how `AuthenticationContext` is exported has changed since then and now it could be imported using ES6 syntax like this:

```
import * as AuthenticationContext from 'adal-angular';
```

**Example**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AdalConfigService } from './adal-config.service';
import * as AuthenticationContext from 'adal-angular';

@Injectable()
export class AdalService {
    private context: AuthenticationContext;
    constructor(private configService: AdalConfigService) {
        this.context = new AuthenticationContext(configService.adalSettings);
    }
    login() {
        this.context.login();
    }
}
```

Comment: The type definition of adal-angular is different from actual types. For example, there is no getCachedUser function on actual code but it exists on the type definition.